# Spectral radius of a matrix

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, spectral-radius

How to show that for a matrix $M$, its spectral radius $\rho(M)$ satisfies $$\rho(M)=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\|M^k\|^{\frac{1}{k}}$$ where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the norm of the matrix?

Comment: This is your second post here that shows no work of your own. That's why you are getting downvotes rather than answers. Please edit the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Took me about 20 seconds to find a proof online.   Try google.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called Gelfand's formula and is on the [Wikipedia page for spectral radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Gelfand's_formula).

Comment: Thanks very much! Sorry I haven't noticed that!